# List users by program

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Having tables like these:

Users:

```
CREATE TABLE `affiliate__model__user_node` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Programs:

```
CREATE TABLE `affiliate__model__program` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Users using programs:

```
CREATE TABLE `affiliate__model__user_program` (
 `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `program_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`program_id`)
)
```

How to effectively list users belonging to a particular program, like this?

```
   user_id    | program 1 | program 2 | program 3 | program N ....
--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------           
         1    |     Y     |      N    |      N    |     Y
         3    |     N     |      N    |      N    |     N
         7    |     N     |      Y    |      N    |     N
         12   |     Y     |      Y    |      Y    |     Y
         n    |     N     |      N    |      N    |     Y
```

(number of programs may change according to the `program` table data, but it's limited to ~20).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following query:

```
SELECT
    user.user_id,
    IF(program.name = 'program 1', 'Y', 'N') AS 'program 1'
    IF(program.name = 'program 2', 'Y', 'N') AS 'program 2'
    IF(program.name = 'program 3', 'Y', 'N') AS 'program 3'
    ...
FROM affiliate__model__user_node user
INNER JOIN affiliate__model__user_program model
ON user.id = model.user_id
INNER JOIN affiliate__model__program program
ON model.program_id = program.id
```

For ~20 program columns this won't win an award for being the prettiest query, but it should get the job done.

Comment: @Sfisioza Please review my answer and let us know if it solved your problem.

Comment: This is not important whether it's `Y/N` or just `0` or `1`, or null/program_id. The point is that the number of columns should be dynamic (depending on the data entered into `program` table.